# Set ssl_certificate path in conf.d in Nginx ingress controller

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I need to set in Nginx ingress controller the conf.d file.
The fields that I need to change is ssl_certificate and ssl_certificate_key.

I will be happy for yaml example.

Answer (score 1):

You can set these fields with configuration parameters of Nginx ingress controller.

There is a nginx ingress controller [argument](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/cli-arguments/) to do this:

```
--default-ssl-certificate: namespace/tls-secret
```

This sets a default certificate in case the ingress resource doesn't specify one.

Also you can set a tls secret per ingress resource:

```
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - my.host.com
    secretName: tls-secret
```

Both those solutions sets `ssl_certificate` and `ssl_certificate_key` in the nginx config